# check time execution on client side

Tags: javascript

Need to check time execution on client side

```js
var start = new Date().getSeconds();
// code...
var end = new Date().getSeconds();
let time = end - start
console.log(time);
```

`Result: 0`;

I suppose it's a part of second, for example `0.05`. How can I get it?

Comment: `Date.now()` gives you milliseconds (thousandths of a second) since The Epoch (midnight Jan 1st 1970 GMT). `performance.now()` gives you the same thing, theoretically with higher precision (through fractional numbers) although most browsers dialled that back after Spectre and Meltdown. There's also `console.time("label")` and `console.timeEnd("label")`, which report the interval between them.

Comment: Seconds are not a fine enough unit to measure this.  Using `Date().getTime() - Date().getTime()` will give you the difference in milliseconds.

Comment: In addtion to not being fine-grained enough, getSeconds() returns the number of seconds since the start of the current minute.  If you start the timer shortly before the end of a minute, and finish early in the next minute, the second value can be smaller.  Most of the time you will just get  0 or 1 as the result, but it could -58 or -59 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getTime()` instead of `getSeconds()` and divide the difference by `1000`.

```js
var start = new Date().getTime();
for(let i = 0;i<100000;i++)
var end = new Date().getTime();
let time = (end - start)/1000
console.log(time);
```